# Explanation on the output of simple SH script

Tags: shell, output, sh

I am very new to sh, and I would like some assistance in understanding the output from the script.

I perform:

```
(echo a b c; echo 1 2 3) > data_file
```

Then I run the Script(run.sh):

```
run.sh < data_file | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'

#!/bin/sh
while read a b
do
echo $a $a $b $b $c $c
echo $a $a $b $b $c $c
done
```

The output becomes:

```
A A B C B C
A A B C B C
1 1 2 3 2 3
1 1 2 3 2 3
```

What I don't understand is why is C being displayed, when the variable $b is in it's position to be printed. Shouldn't it have printed b?  Also, there's no c variable yet a value is being printed in it's position.
I had expected the output to be something like:

```
A A B B
A A B B 
C C 1 1 
C C 1 1
2 2 3 3
2 2 3 3
```

Comment: Hint: simplify the script to `while read a b ; do echo $a ; echo $b ; done`. That should help you to understand what's happening.

Comment: Excellent - don't know why I didn't think of this.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. It's got all the ingredients of a good question -- input data, expected output, actual output, and code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the value of B  stored "B C"

Comment: The reason for this is that if you `read` input that consists of N "words", but you only provide <N variables for read to assign the data to, then after all variables have been exhausted, all remaining words are added to the final variable.  So if you read `eh bee sea` with `read a b`, then `b` is assigned "from the second word to the end of the line".